# Getting to wi-fi login page when DNS resolution is borked

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, display-resolution

A while back I started having trouble with DNS resolution (Ubuntu 20.04). It may have coincided with uninstalling or updating protonvpn or that may have been a coincidence. In any case, I found I could fix it by opening up /etc/resolv.conf and changing the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 . I wrote a script to do that and now I run it every time I start up or un-suspend my computer. I've been doing it for a couple months.

Now I'm in a hotel trying to log into the wifi. But they have a login page I don't know how to find. What can I do?

Comment: Temporarily disable your hack. Temporarily disable protonvpn. Let the Hotel's DHCP server set up everything. Then re-enable

Comment: That's not working. It's running into the same original problem of not getting the right DNS server

Comment: Many VPN providers use their own DNS servers as part of their protection. You may need to remove this VPN altogether and reboot. You can always reinstall it later.